# Correct code will not compile?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

This code seems perfectly fine for me (CS101) but my IDE throws up the error "This method must return a result of type boolean"

I don't want any tips on how to streamline my code or anything like that just want a reason for / solution as to why this is happening

```
public static boolean validation(String correct1, String correct2)
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean correctInput = false;
    String userInput;

    while (correctInput == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Type in " + correct1 + " or " + correct2);
        userInput = in.next();

        if ( userInput.equals(correct1) )
        {
            return true;
        }else if ( userInput.equals(correct2) )
        {
            return false;
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
        }
    }   
}
```

Question is now solved, anyone interested why i needed this full code below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CheckingInput
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("What is 1+1?");
    boolean answer = validation("two", "three");
    if(answer == true)
    {
        System.out.print("Correct!");
    }else if(answer == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Wrong!");
    }
}

public static boolean validation(String correct1, String correct2)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean correctInput = false;
    String userInput;

    while (correctInput == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Type in " + correct1 + " or " + correct2 + ": ");
        userInput = in.next();

        if ( userInput.equals(correct1) )
        {
            correctInput = true;
            return true;

        }else if (userInput.equals(correct2))
        {
            correctInput = true;
            return false;
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
            correctInput = false;
        }
    }   
    return false;// Doesn't really matter, loop will never reach here
}
```

Comment: Then it isn't correct. Does your code return a boolean in **all** cases?

Comment: On another note, why are you using `==` instead of `.equals(` for strings?

Comment: What i want it to do is to repeat the while loop until one of the two if statements are met and a value is returned, and not to exit until they are, am i going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @Chris That works, see my answer. I don't see why you would want to in practice, though; the user should be given a way to exit without having to meet one of the two `if` statements.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how is this a possible duplicate of comparing Strings? It has nothing to do with that

Comment: @hexafraction where is he using `==` for Strings?

Comment: @mikeyaworski i was using == but i have edited my post.

Comment: @Chris Oh ok, but it doesn't say there was an edit on my screen.

Comment: @mike If you edit within 5 minutes of posting, it doesn't show up. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: thanks for you help, this simple task has been annoying me for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the infinite loop is intentional, as you're awaiting a response from your user, so try the following:

```
public static boolean validation(String correct1, String correct2)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Type in " + correct1 + " or " + correct2);
        userInput = in.next();

        if ( userInput.equals(correct1) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( userInput.equals(correct2) )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
        }
    }

    return false; // Doesn't really matter, loop will never reach here
}
```

Comment: This has worked, and i know this wouldn't come up in practice but my lecturer is trying to get us to practice validation techniques without us knowing he is, silly question, silly code

Answer (score 0):

A `return true;` or `return false` statement is missing before the end of the function, in case the loop exits.

Comment: i don't want the loop to exit until one of the two if statements are met and a value is returned.